# Output using foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I am using below mentioned code to fetch the records from a database but the output I am getting is not correct.

Code:

```
$data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `registration`");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($data);
foreach($row as $val)
{
    echo $val."<br>";
}
?>
```

Output:

[image: Getting records of a row twice.]

I want to get records of only 1 row using foreach loop.

Comment: Why do you believe the output to be "not correct" / more than one row? How about `_fetch_assoc`, `print_r`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` fetches result as key, value pair and indexed array combined, why don't you use `mysql_fetch_row` instead.

Comment: @mario, thanks a lot!

Comment: @SomnathSinha, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `mysqli_fetch_array($data)`

try this

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($data,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got the point that foreach was outputting the numeric and associative array.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the MYSQLI_ASSOC constant. So your code should look like:

```
$data=mysqli_query($con,"select * from `registration`");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($row as $val)
{
   echo $val."<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($data);`

A better option is to 
use `mysqli_fetch_array($data,MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

The `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function fetches a result row as an associative array.